# Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to go to a certain  ul tag (27 according to my count), and then parse anchor href and its value.
here is my code

```
$wrss = ("http://www.gazetaexpress.com/");
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($wrss);
$x=$dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
    $item_title=$x->item(26)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $item_title;
```

This gives me the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in 
refering to this line

```
    $item_title=$x->item(26)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

html

```
 <ul class="t_content items">
 <li><div>
 <span class="customfont">17:15 </span>
 <a class="customfont" title ="Vritet një grabitës i armatosur" href="?cid=1,15,76282"> Vritet një grabitës i armatosur </a></div></li> ...
```

any help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMDocument::loadHTML — Load HTML from a string, not from a website address :)
You need to use something like:

```
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($wrss));
```